# Alter postfix reject code and reason

Tags: postfix

I have minimalistic Dovecot + Postfix installation.
Also there is /etc/postfix/sender_access file with few blocked email addresses.

For now postfix replies code 554 to these addresses.

`The error that the other server returned was:
554 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Access denied`

Can I change the code to 550 and reason to "Mailbox not found" ? Is it possible without hacking of Postfix's source code ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `REJECT ACTIONS` in [`man 5 access`](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html). Specifically you'll want to use

```
targetaddress@example.com REJECT 550 Mailbox not found
```

As always, test with `postmap -q "string" /etc/postfix/<your_access_file>`.